# Mediawiki - a quick link to template editor

Tags: syntax, mediawiki, wiki

Wikipedia's navbox templates have `v·t·e` (view, talk, edit) links in upper left corner.

Now I have my own MediaWiki installation and want to be able to edit templates quickly (to have an edit link near each template or more advanced - near each template of certain type).

How to do this?

P.S. I am not sure whether this is the right place to ask such questions, but saw `mediawiki` tag on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The links in navboxes are there, because a navbox template is created using [`Template:Navbox`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template%3aNavbox), which in turn uses [`Template:Navbar`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template%3aNavbar), which actually creates the links.

If you want something similar on your wiki, you can copy `Navbar` from Wikipedia, create your own version of `Navbox` (or whatever) and then use that in the specific templates that you create.

Comment: The actual code to display the edit link: `[{{fullurl:myTemplate|action=edit}} myEditText]`