# Mediawiki - Create a link to a template's edit page

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-templates

I'm making a template, in this template I want to include a link that will send me to its own edit page so that it can be easily accessible from the pages it is included in (very similar to Wikipedia's "view - edit - discuss" links), but I want to do it without extensions. Is it possible? how?

I tried using`[[{{PAGENAME}}?action=edit]]` but it automatically converts that link to `{{PAGENAME}}%26action%3Dedit&action=edit&redlink=1`. Using html anchors doesn't seem to work either, they are not parsed.

Comment: Just replace `{{{PAGENAME}}}` with the name of the template...

Comment: the result is the same: `name-of-the-template%26action%3Dedit&action=edit&redlink=1`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mediawiki - a quick link to template editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24408629/mediawiki-a-quick-link-to-template-editor)